# Prestashop - Get product's id_manufacturer in Ajax cart

Tags: php, ajax, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am working with Prestashop 1.6, and I'd like to know how to retrieve the current product's manufacturer id in the Ajax cart pop-up.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

the id of the producer is present in the product item.
To call uses where you prefer:

```
{$product.id_manufacturer}
```

the file is:

/themes/[name-your-themes]/modules/blockcart/blockcart.tpl

Comment: Thanks but I was actually talking about the file "ajax-cart.js", which doesn't recognize "product.id_manufacturer".

Answer (score 0):

In

```
  \themes\YOUR_THEME\modules\blockcart\blockcart-json.tpl
```

Add

```
"id_manufacturer": {$product.id_manufacturer},
```